# Are there any efforts building an object-CMIS-model-mapper / other higher level abstraction under way?

Tags: alfresco, cmis

Building an object-oriented application on top of CMIS can feel just about as low level as using raw SQL. For SQL databases, we have OR-Mappers such as hibernate or libraries such as ibatis in the java world to provide us with basic CRUD functionality for writing an application.

Of course there is no spec-based API analogous to JDBC (on which the higher level relational "tools" rely) for CMIS, but I guess that does not make a significant difference addressing the issue.

Are there any efforts making the life of CMIS-App developers a little more convenient ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html. It is mainly developed for Java but is available (at different "stability") for python, .net and phph